# HDFS yarn nodemanager not starting completely

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am facing an issue from past few days, 
If I use Hadoop 2.7.4, I am not able to start nodemanager's at slaves with this version, because of this I can't run any mapred jobs.

When I use Hadoop 2.8.2, everything is starting well(start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh) and I am able to see the content, nodes activity at http://:50070, but while running my programs that use data from HDFS, it keeps on displaying

> 17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero

but the job runs well. I am not aware of this issue and how it is effected. So, I tried 2.7.3

When I tried 2.7.3, I am not facing the above error, but I see that the yarn are not starting completing and when I start yarn, it throws more line on screen that usual way and it starts. The main issue, in this case, I am not able to watch watch going on in hadoop from web url as here it doesn't display anything on web, except for those files present in HDFS(So, I am only able see the data from Utilities --> Browse files )

The error is similar to this:

> starting yarn daemons
>
> starting resourcemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn--resourcemanager-hadoop-master.out
>
> Nov 20, 2017 8:01:28 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   as a provider class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 8:01:28 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebServices as
>   a root resource class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 8:01:28 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider
>   class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 8:01:28 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011
>   11:17 AM'
>
> Nov 20, 2017 8:01:28 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   getComponentProvider
>
> INFO: Binding
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
>
> hadoop-slave1: Warning: Permanently added 'hadoop-slave1,10.40.0.0'
>   (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> hadoop-slave1: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-hadoop-slave1.weave.local.out

Any idea how to set it up completely without any issue?

Comment: You should copy here the exact lines it throws, not just mention that they are 'more'. Also, look at the logs of each of the services involved (nodemanager on each node, resourcemanager on the head)

Comment: I have updated the similar error I faced!! Please check it @RemusRusanu

Comment: Anything other than `INFO` level? Errors? Warnings?

Comment: No, nothing other than that. Infact my job is running well in this case, but I am not able to see anything over web, except for the files. As mentioned before with v2.8.2, I don't have this INFO level and I am able to see everything over web, but I have this "WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero" and in this case as well my job runs, but not sure what this warning is about is!!!. @RemusRusanu

Comment: @RemusRusanu I have updated the error when initializing yarn. Please take a look. Let me know, if you have a solution to this.